# An updating cursor with postgresql with python API

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I am using postgresql 9.x with pyscopg2. Is there a cursor or some other object that can be used to notify of any changes to the underlying table(s). At present I poll the db and then have to loop through the rows determining if there is any new data and/or if any existing data already exists. Afterwards I have to loop through the data I have and make sure none have been deleted in the tables. Not very efficient. I have just started using postgresql and am only a DB apprentice. Any help with documentation would help. thanks

Comment: Try reading this http://www.divillo.com/ and http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/advanced.html

Comment: I think you want `LISTEN` and `NOTIFY`